# How do I popup modal in the beginning? React-native navigation

Tags: react-native

I am using react navigation v5 to create my modal.

I want my modal to show in the beginning of 50% height, and when I press a button I want my modal to have 100% height. And toggle 50% to 100% to 50% back and forth.

However, I am unsure how to do this.
My code looks something like this.

Navigation

```
render(){
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <RootStack.Navigator mode="modal" headerMode = "none">
                    <RootStack.Screen name="home" component = {Home} />
                    <RootStack.Screen name="modala" component={ModalA} 
                    options={{cardStyle: {backgroundColor: "transparent"}}}/>
                </RootStack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
```

As you can see I want my modalA to overlap Home component in the beginning as 50% width and if i press a button inside ModalA, I want my modal to be 100%. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, its possible. To show the modal on the initial screen you must create this [Modal Component](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) on that screen
e.g

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

const Home = (props) => {

    const [height, setHeight] = useState('50%');

    return (
      <View>
        <Modal isVisible={true}>
          <View style={{ height, width: "80%", justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text>I am the modal content!</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setHeight("50%")}>
              <Text>Set 50% Height</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setHeight("100%")}>
              <Text>Set 100% Height</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in React Navigation?

Comment: Mmm what you could do is create a screen that always shows the modal and put it in the navigation so that you do a navigation.navigate(" Modal ") but I would think that it is better to do only the component of the modal and this call it on the screens you need it